# Daily average from a 15mins interval datetime column o

Tags: sql-server, group-by, datetime, date

[image: Input Table]

I want to convert this 15 minutes interval data into daily average such that in the output file, I should have only two columns 'Date' and 'Daily_Avg_Value'.

This is my first post here - really wish to get some help on this. Thanks.

The output table should like below.

Note: I don't have any gaps in the table and it is 15mins interval data.

[image]

Comment: Why is the result for 14/05/2020 545? The sample data suggests the correct value is 538.6666666666667

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Please take your time to read [ask]. If possible don't add screenshots as explained in the [Question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/15356) & [Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1820861) in **Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?** from Stack Overflow Meta Site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to cast your `TimestampLocal` column to a `DATE` so everything on the same day has the same value, and then use a [`GROUP BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause on that value. Then you can divide the `SUM(Value)` by the `COUNT_BIG(*)` of rows, like so:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, TimestampLocal) AS [Date],
    SUM([Value]) / (COUNT_BIG(*) * 1.0) AS Daily_Avg_Value
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, TimestampLocal)
```

Note I multiplied the `COUNT_BIG(*)` by `1.0` as a shortcut to casting the result to a decimal. Also, `COUNT_BIG(*)` instead of `COUNT_BIG(SomeColumn)` ensures that `NULL`s are included in the count. (Not sure if your column is nullable, but just something to be aware of.)

You can also use the [`AVG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) aggregate function too, but this would not count rows with `NULL` values also.